# arquillian @Drone injections always returning "about:blank" page

Tags: maven, jsf, jboss, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I am having this problem for 2 days now, and I am tending to think that something in my configuration is off. I'll post first my code and then explain:

```
public class MyTest extends Arquillian {

@Deployment(name = "MyPlatform", testable = false)
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {

    WebArchive war;
    war = ShrinkWrap
            .create (WebArchive.class, "MyPlatform.war")
            .merge (Maven
                   .resolver()
                   .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                   .resolve("MyPlatform:My.Platform:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
                   .withoutTransitivity()
                   .asSingle(WebArchive.class));
    return war;
}


@Drone
private PhantomJSDriver browser;

@ArquillianResource
private URL deploymentUrl;

@Test(dataProvider = Arquillian.ARQUILLIAN_DATA_PROVIDER) 
@RunAsClient
public void should_login_successfully(@InitialPage LoginPage loginPage) {
    System.out.println ("ACTUAL: " + browser.getCurrentUrl ());
    System.out.println ("DEPLOYMENT URL: " + deploymentUrl.toExternalForm ());
    loginPage.login ("demo", "demo");

    Assert.assertEquals (deploymentUrl.toExternalForm () + "index.tm", "https://127.0.0.1:8443/MyPlatform/index.tm");
}
```

The @ArquillianResource injection works fine, and shows the correct URL. However the @Drone injection shows "about:blank". after some testing i found something weird:

if my war file is called something like MyPlatform.blabla.war, then the Drone trancates after the first "dot" and i get "`http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyPlatform/login.tm`" which is not what i deployed...so for some reason the @Drone is always trancating my deployment URL and cant seem to find the root of it.

here is my POM just in case

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-impl-base</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphene-webdriver-spi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphene-webdriver-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-testng-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bsh</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I would be greatful if someone can help me in solving this pickle..!

Answer (score 0):

Typical, After I posted the question i found the problem, and it was simply that my applicaiton is running over SSL and phantomjs is not redirecting from 8080 -> 8443...

Now to figure out how to do this ...

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I am facing the same problem and not able to access https urls.